# Using python and spacy text summarization

Tags: python, spacy

Basically i am trying to do text summarize using spacy and nltk in python. Now i want to summarize the normal 6-7 lines text and show the summarized text on the `localhost:xxxx` so whenever i run that python file it will show on the `localhost`.

Can anyone tell is it possible or not and if it is possible how to do this. Since there would be no databse involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a RESTFUL Api using FLASK or DJAngo with some UI elements and call your model. Also you can use displacy( Spacy UI Bro) Directly on your system.

Comment: So first i have to create REST api using FLASK after that i can call that model. right?
and using displacy i don't know how to do if you have any idea how to do than please provide me some links .

Comment: yes you are right using desplacy it's working...i am trying and little it's showing output....thank you so much.